# How do I add trainable scalar parameters to tensorflow graph with keras backend

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I want to approximate the function g(x) = exp(x) with a linear combination of functions, h(x) = sum_i(a_i * f_i(x)) using a neural network with TF2.

Now, the network input is just x and the outputs are the functions f_i.

The custom loss function is simple: the mean squared difference |g(x) - h(x)|^2.

My problem is that I don't understand how to define/use a_i?

First, all a_i are just  scalars, In addition they don't depend on x.

Defining a_i as inputs doesn't make sense since I want them to be optimized.

Defining as outputs makes them depend on x which I don't want.

How can I add these variables as scalars to the network and make them optimized by the optimization process ?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During training, Tensorflow tracks all `tf.Variable` objects defined in the model. If you define your constant as a `tf.Variable`, it will be ajusted via backpropagation.

Let's say we have a dataset wi `X`, and `y` which is `y = X * 2`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.random.uniform((10_000, 1))
y = x * 2
```

We will create a model which has a constant inside, which will need to replicate the relationship between `X` and `y`. We will of course initialize this value as something other than 2. The relationship between `X` and `y` is 2 so the training should make the constant converge towards 2. So let's define a model that is nothing but a constant.

```
class CustomModel(tf.keras.models.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomModel, self).__init__()
        self.constant = tf.Variable(initial_value=0.1, dtype=tf.float32, trainable=True)

    def call(self, x, **kwargs):
        x = self.constant * x
        return x


model = CustomModel()
```

Now just compile and train the model:

```
model.compile(loss='mae')

history = model.fit(x, y, epochs=25, verbose=0)
```

Now look at the weights. The constant, which was initialized with value 0.1, is now 2. It was optimized, as it understood the relationship between `X` and `y`, which is 2.

```
model.weights
```

```
[<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=2.0>]
```

Comment: thanks, but how is this variable can be accessed in the custom loss function which needs it to compute the squared difference?

Comment: You can access it by various ways, like `model.weights` or `model.constant`, but the loss is usually calculated with the output, and not the weights.

Comment: like `loss = loss_function(y_test, model(X_test))`

Comment: Specifically in this case I have to use the variables (the a_i) since I need them to compute the approximation of the function

Comment: Ok ok. Well `constant` is an object attribute so you can most easily access it as such - `model.constant`